# How to avoid using the Object Manager in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, dependency-injection

From [this website](http://mage2docs.com/docs/manually-load-object-manager/):

> ### Manually Load Object Manager
>
> You should avoid calling the object manager directly as this is not the proper way, but if you have to you use:
>
> ```
> $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
> /* use object manager to get a class for example the attribute repository */
> $attr = $om->get('\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface');
> /* use returned class attribute repository to get the attribute id of
> the name for products */
> $productNameAttributeId = $attr->get('catalog_product', 'name')->getId();
> ```

It states:

> **this is not proper way, but if you have to you use**

How can I do this the proper way?

Comment: Have a read at _why_ you shouldn't use the `ObjectManager` directly, as M2 doesn't expand on that: https://mwop.net/blog/2016-04-26-on-locators.html

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to use dependency injection in your class constructor:

```
protected $_attributeRepoInterface;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepoInterface
) {
    $this->_attributeRepoInterface = $attributeRepoInterface;
    parent::_construct(...);
}
```

Then later in your code, you can use the protected variable directly:

```
$this->_attributeRepoInterface->get('catalog_product','name')->getId();
```